# How to handle key events in wxWidgets console application?

Tags: c++, console-application, keyboard-events, wxwidgets

There are lots of resources about how to write GUI applications with wxWidgets (probably, because it is GUI framework :)), but not too much about writing console application. If someone can point me to such resource, I would be grateful.

Specifically, I wonder if it is possible (or how is it possible?) to handle key events in the console application. I.e. I have no shown windows, but I have console. And I want to print out something into this console, when user presses some key on the keyboard while this console window is active.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a task so much for `wxWidgets`, but more for a library like `ncurses` which is made specifically for command-line user interfaces. `ncurses` should come preinstalled on most *nix distros

Have some docs: 
http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/

EDIT:

If you happen to be running Windows, `ncurses` won't work. Instead you'll have to use a clone of it called [`pdcurses`](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But my situation is that I already have wxWidgets in my project, that's why I wanted to use it if possible. I expected, that wxWidgets can handle system events, and as a special case, console events. But if it is not easily possible, I'll find other solution. And yes, I work on windows, so I'd rather use pdcurses.